# Why creating a jQuery object from another jQuery object?

Tags: jquery

Once you have a jQuery object like the one you get by doing:

```
var car = $('li .car');
```

I saw code doing the following:

```
var carChildren = $(car).children('span');
```

What is the point of it?
Why not just use the `.children` method on the already jQuery var car like so?

```
var carChildren = car.children('span');
```

Comment: The point is *wrong usage*. Don't do this.

Comment: there is no point in recreating jquery object of existing object. Use second approach.

Comment: When one is making a polymorphic function that accepts string selectors, jquery objects, dom nodes etc he/she might need it `function doSmthToCar(car) { $(car).children(...)}` even if you are passing jquery object `var car = $(); doSmthToCar(car)`. Otherwise it is just a wrong usage.

Answer (score 1):

**In short:**
There is no reason for doing this. But it makes no difference in result too. It's basically just *bad practice*. So don't do it.

---

**TL;DR**
As said before, it makes no sense and it makes no difference. Let's think about what the lines do. To be clear we write it in one line:

```
var car = $('li .car');
var carChildren = $(car).children('span');
```

Is the same as:

```
var carChildren = $($('li .car')).children('span');
```

Nobody would ever do it this way! The reason someone would write `$(car)` is that they meight be confused by things like `$(this)`, what often is write many times right after.

**Why does it work anyway?**

If you write `$(car)` jQuery will notice that `car` is already a jQuery object and replace it as it's context. But that is a unnecessary task what can be saved.

This said, you can directly use `car` as context too.

```
var carChildren = $('span', car);
```

Comment: The flexibility is probably seen as a bonus, but it really lets you do some crazily stupid things also.